# Why using mAP (mean Average Precision) instead directly computing AP (Average Precision)

Tags: precision-recall, object-detection

## Problem

mAP is a metric frequently used in tasks involving ranking. One application of mAP is in object detection, where for each category

1. The predicted bounding box is organized in decreasing order according to their confidence score.
2. The cumulative TP and FP are computed for each image.
3. The precision and recall for each image is computed using cumulative TP and FP.
4. Compute AP (Average Precision) in Precision-Recall curve through 11-point interpolation.

When AP is computed for each category, the final mAP are given through averaging all AP belonging to different categories.

Even though this does some make sense to me, I am wondering why we bother defining mAP instead of just using AP, where we just combine all categories together and do the four steps I describe above. Is there any rationale behind defining mAP?